# Logic inconsistence with $f(x)=0.16\rightarrow 1-x\geq 0.8$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have this function $f$ given by:

$$f(x)=x(1-x)$$

where $x$ is a real number in $[0, 1]$. I was supposed to find the logic value of

$$f(x)=0.16\rightarrow 1-x\geq 0.8$$

As I see this question does not make sense or we can't find the answer. Let me explain my reasoning. As I see, the logic value of $f(x)=0.16\rightarrow 1-x\geq 0.8$ can only be determined once $x$ is known. For instance:

- If $x=0.8$ then $f(x)=0.16$ and $f(x)=0.16$ is true, whereas $1-0.8\geq 0.8$ is false. Hence, $$f(x)=0.16\rightarrow 1-x>0.8$$ is false.
- On the other hand, if $x=0.2$ then $f(x)=0.16$ and $f(x)=0.16$ is true, whereas $1-0.2\geq 0.8$ is true. Therefore, $$f(x)=0.16\rightarrow 1-x\geq 0.8$$ is true.

As it seems the answer to the questions would be that the logic value of $f(x)=0.16\rightarrow 1-x\geq 0.8$ depends on the value of $x$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn’t depend on the value of $x$. It’s false, because not *all* possible values of $x$ which make $f(x)=0.16$ true, also make $1-x\ge 0.8$ true.

Comment: @Tavish You seem to be referring to the formula $\forall x\,(f(x)=0.16\to1-x\geq0.8)$. But for the formula in the question, without the universal quantifier, the truth value can depend on $x$. The tag "propositional calculus" strongly suggests that the quantifier was not intended.

Comment: You’re correct. Without a quantifier, the truth value of this formula depends on the value of $x$. This is not necessarily a problem, except if you are required to give a single true-or-false answer in which case either the problem is not well-posed or you overlooked a specification somewhere that such formulas come with implicit quantifiers for all of their variables (probably a “forall” as in Tavish’s comment).

Comment: That is right, I was supposed to give a true or false answer. There was no quantifier at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=0.16\rightarrow 1-x\geq 0.8$$ is an open formula, i.e., a formula with free variable(s). Some open formulae have fixed truth values, but such is not the case here, since, as you pointed out, this formula is true when $x=0.2$ but false when $x=0.8.$

(On the other hand, all closed formulae, i.e., formulae with no free variable—also known as propositions/sentences—have definite truth values.)