# First-order Logic Formalisation Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am having trouble with formalising the following two sentences:

(a) A person who is not registered as a student is not entitled to take the Philosophy exam.

(b) Ant is not entitled to take part in any activity in the School

For (a) my attempt is ∀x(Px → ∀y(Sy → ¬Rxy) → ¬Exp)

Formalisation Key:

Px: x is a person

Sx: x is a student

Rxy: x is registered as y

Exy: x is entitled to take y

p: is the Philosophy exam

Does this make sense? Would it be alright to leave the universal quantifiers separated in this way?

For (b) my attempt is ∀x(Ax ∧ Ixs → ¬Tax).

Key:

Ax: x is an activity

Ixy: x is in y

Txy: x is entitled to take part in y

s: is 'the school'

Would it be right to formalise 'the school' as an individual constant 's' (i.e. that 'the school' is referring to some specific school in a domain and this is its name) ??. Thanks.

Comment: Your (a) is correct, but more complex than it needs to be. You don't really need the 2-place predicate "R", nor the subformula that uses it. Consider $\forall x\,(P(x) \land \neg S(x) \rightarrow \neg E(x, p))$, where $S(x)$ means "$x$ is registered as a student", and $E(x,y)$ means "$x$ is entitled to participate in school activity y". This should suggest an approach to (b).

Answer (score 1):

> (a) A person who is not registered as a student is not entitled to
> take the Philosophy exam.

Letting the universe of discourse be the set of persons, the simplest formalisation is $$\forall x \;(Ex\to Sx).$$ A literal and self-contained formalisation is $$∀x \;(Px\to¬Sx\to ¬Ex)$$ (note that this is read as $∀x \;(Px\to(¬Sx\to ¬Ex)),$ which is equivalent to $$∀x \;((Px\land ¬Sx)\to ¬Ex)$$ as well as $$∀x \;((Px\land Ex)\to Sx).$$

Your attempt doesn't look correct:

1. > ¬Exp
   > p: is the Philosophy exam

   Why is the symbolisation key interpreting/restricting a variable?
2. > Rxy: x is registered as y

   What does it mean to say that a variable is registered as another
   variable?
3. > $∀x(Px → ∀y(Sy → ¬Rxy) → ¬Exp)$

   contains an unquantified variable, $p,$ so technically is [not a
   sentence/proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4150974/21813).

> (b) Ant is not entitled to take part in any activity in the School

Letting the universe of discourse be the set of activities, this can be formalised as $$∀x\;(Sx\to¬Ax).$$ If you don't wish to specify the universe of discourse, then: $$∀x\;(Cx\to Sx\to¬Ax),$$ which can be simplified as in the previous example.

(a**C**tivity, **S**chool, **A**nt)

> For (b) my attempt is $∀x(Ax ∧ Ixs → ¬Tax).$
>  Ax: x is an
> activity
>  Ixy: x is in y
>  Txy: x is entitled to take part in
> y
>  s: is 'the school'

You accidentally omitted the last line: “a: (is) Ant.” In any case, this attempt has the same issues as above. In particular, none of ‘Philosophy exam’, ‘school’ and ‘Ant’ needs to be a variable.